# Integration of the cosine function in Fourier transform

Tags: integration, fourier-analysis

How do I integrate the following:
$$\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty(e^{iax}+e^{-iax})e^{-ikx-b|x|}dx $$

The answer is $$\frac{b}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\left(\frac{1}{(a-k)^2+b^2}+\frac{1}{(a+k)^2+b^2}\right)$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\begin{align}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx\,  e^{i (a-k) x}\,  e^{-b |x|} &= \int_{-\infty}^0 dx\, e^{(b+i (a-k)) x} + \int_0^{\infty} dx \, e^{-(b-i (a-k)) x}\\&=\int_0^{\infty} dx \, e^{-(b+i (a-k)) x} + \int_0^{\infty} dx \, e^{-(b-i (a-k)) x}\\&= \frac{1}{b+i(a-k)} + \frac{1}{b-i(a-k)}\\ &= \frac{2 b}{b^2+(a-k)^2}\end{align}$$

Similarly,

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx\,  e^{-i (a+k) x}\,  e^{-b |x|} = \frac{2 b}{b^2+(a+k)^2}$$

The result follows.

Comment: ok, am I right to say that b has to be greater than 0, but no such restriction applies to (a-k)?

Comment: @user91820: correct.